# multiple queues consuming in one channel

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I use rabbitMq for manage and work with queues. I have multiple queues. the count of them is n't specific. I use direct exchange for publishing messages.
how can I consume all messages of each queues (based on routing_key) using only one
channel?
at this time I assume  i have 5 queues. I've used for loop and create a channel per queue. like this:

```
 stuff=["shoes","pants","hats","jewels","glasses"];

  stuff.forEach(cnt => 
    {
        var ex = 'stuff';
        var cq=cnt;

        amqp
        .connect('amqp://localhost')
        .then(conn => conn.createChannel())
        .then(ch => {

            ch.assertExchange(ex, 'x-delayed-message', { durable: true, 
     arguments: { 'x-delayed-type': 'direct' } })
     return ch
             .assertQueue(cq, { durable: true })
             .then(() =>  {   ch.bindQueue(cq, ex, cq)  /*second cq is routing*/  
                 })
                  .then(() => {
                  ch.consume(cq, (msg) =>
                  {

                   console.log("['%s']  '%s'",cq, msg.content.toString()); 
                   if( msg.content.toString()!=null)
                   console.log(cq);

                          reciveMSG=JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());

                    }, { noAck: true });
               }); 
         }) 


     });
```

but I wanna do it only with one channel. because its more optimistic and use less memory(i do n't know it is true or not!).is there a way for handle unspecific count of queues?

Comment: node sample code rabbitmq , multi-Queues , single channel https://github.com/heroku-examples/node-articles-nlp/blob/master/lib/app/index.js#L9

Comment: Note that that code is not using a single channel, because you *must* use at least one channel per-queue to consume messages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *can* use one channel to consume from several queues, but you'll receive messages one-by-one, even if they are coming from different queues. I'm pretty sure a channel exception on one queue will stop consuming from all queues.

Comment: You mean I ask my question there again?

Comment: No, that is a footer I include to tell people that the best place to ask RabbitMQ questions is the mailing list, not stack overflow.

Comment: @LukeBakken I'm using the node client and currently using the same channel to consume on multiple queues, everything is running fine as well. I'm sure you're more experienced than me in rabbit, should I move to a multi-channel setup?

Comment: @LukeBakken - Luke, the official docs state "...limiting the number of channels used per connection is highly recommended", recommend pooling channels (so it seems re-using with various queues) and don't mention the one channel per queue rule at all (https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html). Can you please clarify and give more context to your answer? Thanks in advance.