# Prevent creating multiple connections in RabbitMQ while using RabbitMQ Bundle for the Symfony2

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I'm using [RabbitMQ Bundle for the Symfony2 web framework](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle). My question is, how can I avoid creating multiple connections ([to prevent overloading the broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418936/rabbitmq-and-relationship-between-channel-and-connection)) after running many workers in terminal? In example below, I've run two workers and ended up having two connections/channel.

**config.yml**

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host:     127.0.0.1
            port:     5672
            user:     guest
            password: guest
            vhost:    /
            lazy:     true
    producers:
        order_create_bmw:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: { name: order_create_ex, type: direct }
            queue_options:
                name: order_create_bmw_qu
                routing_keys:
                    - bmw
    consumers:
        order_create_bmw:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: { name: order_create_ex, type: direct }
            queue_options:
                name: order_create_bmw_qu
                routing_keys:
                    - bmw
            callback:         application_frontend.consumer.order_create_bmw
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    application_frontend.producer.order_create_bmw:
        class: Application\FrontendBundle\Producer\OrderCreateBmwProducer
        arguments:
            - @old_sound_rabbit_mq.order_create_bmw_producer
```

**Producer**

```
namespace Application\FrontendBundle\Producer;

use Application\FrontendBundle\Entity\Order;
use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ProducerInterface;

class OrderCreateBmwProducer
{
    private $producer;

    public function __construct(ProducerInterface $producer)
    {
        $this->producer = $producer;
    }

    public function add(Order $order)
    {
        $message = [
            'order_id' => $order->getId(),
            'car_model' => $order->getCarModel(),
            'timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ];

        $this->producer->publish(json_encode($message), 'bmw');
    }
}
```

**Running workers**

```
$ app/console rabbitmq:consumer order_create_bmw
$ app/console rabbitmq:consumer order_create_bmw
```

**RabbitMQ Management**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Every client (regardless if publisher or subscriber) that connects to rabbitmq will create a connection. Aside from using less clients, I can't think of any other way to achive this. I also can't think of a reason to do so :) If it's performance, than actually having more subscribers will help to "empty" the exchanges (and queues).